# Why is the Apps flash storage so high and how can it be reduced?

Tags: flash-memory

This is the disk storage info:

[image]

This is the Applications folder info:

[image]

Why is the storage usage so high and how can it be reduced? This is on a MacBook Pro Retina 13" with OSX 10.9.5.

Edit: I had tried all the suggestions made by @user3439894 in his answer but didn't mention it before posting.